# Downloads from Github Repo in R Keeps Failing

Tags: r, devtools

Im trying to access a dataset from a repo on Github but the download keeps failing.  The code that im using is

```
install.packages("devtools")
library(devtools)
devtools::install_github("rich-iannone/intendo")
```

I keep getting the following error;

```
Downloading GitHub repo rich-iannone/intendo@HEAD
Error in utils::download.file(url, path, method = method, quiet = quiet,  : 
  download from 'https://api.github.com/repos/rich-iannone/intendo/tarball/HEAD' failed
```

What am I doing wrong? Im using R 4.1.1 and RStudio 2021.09.0

Comment: I cannot reproduce, that exact code works fine ok on my system.

Comment: I am able to reproduce your error, if I go behind a firewall and try to run the `devtools::github(..)` line of your code. As soon as I disconnect from the VPN, I'm able to download without a problem

Comment: This issue is due the package it self [see that](https://github.com/rich-iannone/intendo/issues/1)

Comment: Im trying to access from outside the US so maybe that's the issue..but the thing is when I use a VPN and set a virtual location of the US etc it still doesn't work...which I find odd. @DohamedDesouky I note that there has been no response to the issue which has been cited by others..

Comment: The problem is happen to me and i'm outside USA

Comment: @langtang what makes it all the more puzzling is that my VPN shows that I ve downloaded some 300MB of data prior to getting the error message

Comment: It is basically about the connection  some one share the same issue now in github

Answer (score 3):

I've encountered same problem recently and it seems it's due to slow connection. So I extended the timeout default limit before installing the package.

```
options(timeout=400)
```

And it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I essentially had to download the file manually, [here](https://github.com/rich-iannone/intendo) and then load into RStudio.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).